# Can anyone help me with the debugger?

Tags: debugging, assembly

I just opened cmd prompt on Windows 7 (32 bit), I typed `debug` and then I pressed the <kbd>Return</kbd> Key.

The first instruction goes fine, the same for the second and third instruction, but not for the fourth one.

```
mov bl,3f
mov dl,20
mov [20],bl
mov [03ab],[dl]
            ^error
```

Why doesn't the debugger let me do that?

Comment: 1. Which debbuger? 2. What do you mean "doesn't let you do that"?

Comment: I just opened cmd prompt on Windows 7 (32 bit), I typed "debug" and then I pressed the "Return" Key. The first instruction goes fine, the same for the second and third instruction, but not for the fourth one. Sorry, but I'm not english and I'm trying to describe the problem.  (I'm Italian :D )

Comment: That instruction is entirely impossible, you can't even assemble it, much less run it

Answer (score 0):

Because, as far as I remember, the `mov` instruction cannot move between two memory positions.

You should load into a register, then from the register store in the other address.

Also you could set up the `di` and `si` registers and use `movsb/w/d/whatever`.

note: I assume you are using 16 bit code.